# How to set up a google map, which allows users to add new markers but not to edit or change already existing ones?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know my question isn't very specific and quite general. Sorry about that. I'm new to google maps API and unsure what would be the optimal or typical approach. If you could just steer me in the general direction...

I want to set up a website, with the following functionality:

- displaying a map with markers, highlighting POI's of the users
- everyone should be able to add additional markers (ideally with title, description and a photo)
- BUT: the old markers are not to be changed by anyone but me
- Do I have to worry about API requests? For example, if 100 markers are set and 1000 users load the website would that already result in 100.000 requests?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Regarding requests: what about reading the documentation regarding API usage and limits? Regarding who can modify markers, this is purely general, broad application design and concepts. Please read, try and ask another question if you have a specific issue with some code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment... I read the google maps API documentation and I came up with a general idea of how to code my project. I just wondered if it is the most efficient way and how to avoid common pitfalls...

Comment: As I said, your question is too broad and more about concepts and application and/or database design. There is no "best way" to do what you described. It all depends on what you need, how you want it to work, etc. Further to that, we don't even know what language(s) or framework(s) you want to program with. This is why you have to read or try by yourself to find out what will work for your use case. We can't tell you.

Comment: I see your point... This will be my first project that supports user interaction so I'm flying blind and just want to start in the right direction... anyway, I will set up a first working example, probably based on html and java, to see where exactly problems occur

Answer (score 1):

Added the code implementation (just the client side). But little tweaks need to be made, in order to work as required.

> 1. Displaying a map with markers, highlighting POI's of the users

This need to be done with a backend server. On page load, get the details as response from the server and save it in the `markers` array. Once loaded iterate the array and add the markers while initializing the map.

> 2. Everyone should be able to add additional markers (ideally with title, description and a photo)

Added the functionality in the below code. But the data will not be stored in backend (it need to be implemented based on the requirements). For now, the marker details are stored in the local `markers` array. Make sure to add it to the array only after saving it in the database.

> 3. The old markers are not to be changed by anyone but Me.

Added those functionalities to (but only as a static). Need to check the user scope before editing/deleting the markers and it has to be implemented based on your requirements.

> 4. Do I have to worry about API requests? For example, if 100 markers are set and 1000 users load the website would that already result in 100.000 requests?

The API requests are only for maps, not for markers. As per [Google Guides](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage), 25000 requests are free per 24 hrs. Refer the pricing page for more info, if the request exceeds the free limit.

P.S : 1. Add your API key in the script. 2. Used [Javascript Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in scripting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .googlemap
        {
            margin : 0 auto;
            height : 600px;
            width : 600px;
        }
        .main_content
        {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .infowin
        {
            width:250px;
            max-height:200px;
            padding : 5px;
            background: #fab9b9;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        .infowin_img
        {
            float:left;
            margin:0;
            width:70px;
            height: 100%;
            background: #0db99e;
        }
        .infowin_img > img
        {
            height: 100%;
            width: 70px;
        }
        .infowin_content
        {
            float: left;
            margin:0;
            background: #1e72d3;
            height:100%;
            width :180px;
            color:white;
            padding: 5px;
            overflow: scroll;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .btn_div
        {   
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .button
        {
            padding: 3px;
            width:100px;
            color:white;
            cursor:pointer;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .edit_btn
        {
            border: 1px solid #277107;
            background: #2e8608;
        }
        .edit_btn:hover
        {
            background: #206004;
        }
        .remove_btn
        {
            border: 1px solid #e54646;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: #dd5f5f;
        }
        .remove_btn:hover
        {
            background: #e32424;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="googlemap" class="googlemap"></div>
    <div id="form" hidden>
      <table>
          <tr><td>Name:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>
          <tr><td>Description:</td> <td><input type='text' id='description'/> </td> </tr>
          <tr><td>Image:</td> <td><input type='file' id='photo'/> </td> </tr>
          <tr><td></td> <td><input type='button' value='Save' onclick="GoogleMap.saveLocation()"/> </td> </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="infowin" hidden>
        <div class="infowin">
            <div class="main_content">
                <div class="infowin_img">
                    <img src="dummy.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="infowin_content">
                    <span>PLACE_NAME</span><br>
                    <span>PLACE_DESCRIPTION</span><br>
                    <span>Added by : ADDED_BY</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn_div">
                <div class="button edit_btn" onclick="GoogleMap.editLocation()">Edit Location</div>
                <div class="button remove_btn" onclick="GoogleMap.removeLocation()">Remove Location</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var CommonUtil = (function(){
            return {
                getInputValue : function(id){
                    return document.getElementById(id).value;
                },
                setInputValue : function(id, value){
                    document.getElementById(id).value = value;
                }
            };
        })();
        var GoogleMap = (function(){
            var map, selectedmarker, markers=[], infowindow;
            var formcontent = document.getElementById("form").innerHTML,
                detailscontent = document.getElementById("infowin").innerHTML;

            return {
                initialize : function(){
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemap'), {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.302516, 16.414546), //Setting Initial Position
                        zoom: 6,
                    });
                    map.addListener("click",function(event){
                        GoogleMap.addLocation(event.latLng);
                    })
                },
                addLocation : function(latlng){
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        label: markers.length+1
                    });
                    marker.addListener("click",function(){
                        selectedmarker=this;
                        GoogleMap.showPlaceDetailsToUser(this);
                    });
                    GoogleMap.getPlaceDetailsFromUser(marker);
                    markers.push(marker);
                    selectedmarker=marker;
                },
                removeLocation : function(){
                    markers.splice(markers.indexOf(selectedmarker),1);
                    if(selectedmarker)
                    {
                        selectedmarker.setMap(null);
                    }
                },
                editLocation : function(){
                    GoogleMap.showPlaceDetailsToUser(selectedmarker,true);
                    CommonUtil.setInputValue("name",selectedmarker.placeInfo.name);
                    CommonUtil.setInputValue("description",selectedmarker.placeInfo.description);
                    CommonUtil.setInputValue("photo",selectedmarker.placeInfo.photo);
                },
                saveLocation : function(){
                    selectedmarker.placeInfo = selectedmarker.placeInfo || {};
                    selectedmarker.placeInfo.name = CommonUtil.getInputValue("name")
                    selectedmarker.placeInfo.description = CommonUtil.getInputValue("description");
                    selectedmarker.placeInfo.photo = CommonUtil.getInputValue("photo");
                    selectedmarker.placeInfo.addedBy = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
                    GoogleMap.showPlaceDetailsToUser(selectedmarker);
                },
                getPlaceDetailsFromUser : function(marker){
                    GoogleMap.showInfoWindow(formcontent, marker);
                },
                showPlaceDetailsToUser : function(marker, isedit){
                    var content = marker.placeInfo && !isedit ? detailscontent.replace("PLACE_NAME",marker.placeInfo.name||"NO_NAME").replace("PLACE_DESCRIPTION",marker.placeInfo.description||"NO_DESCRIPTION").replace("ADDED_BY",marker.placeInfo.addedBy) : formcontent;
                    GoogleMap.showInfoWindow(content, marker);
                },
                showInfoWindow : function(content, marker){
                    if(infowindow) infowindow.close();

                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:content});
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            }
        })();
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=GoogleMap.initialize" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your trouble... this is very helpful... I'm still struggling with the backend side/database but I will dive in a bit deeper myself to come up with specific questions. Thanks a lot!